# Unable to bundle in JRUBY environment

Tags: java, bundler, jruby

I have installed the bundler in ruby environment and able to do

```
 bundle install
```

but when i am doing

```
 bundle install
```

in jruby environment it give the following

```
 zsh: command not found: bundle
```

when i am going to install bundler using

```
 gem install bundler
```

in jruby environment it give the following

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jruby/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

I am totally confused what is going on please help me to solve this problem, I spend to days in the same but unable to resolve it.

Comment: Is your Java 1.8 or higher? https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/5247

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried java8 but no use. then java11 but no use.